# How to avoid ConcurrentModificationException when using ArrayList?

Tags: java, android

How to avoid `ConcurrentModificationException` when using `ArrayList` on Android?

Can someone give the basic rule of thumb to avoid it?

Comment: Are you talking about `ConcurrentModificationException`? If you want good help, you need to provide exact details of your problem.

Comment: are you using arraylist method to remove?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By not adding/removing the elements when iterating over your arraylist.

This code would throw the ConcurrentModificationException as you are modifying the list while iterating.

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
al.add("2");
for(String s: al) {
al.remove("2");
}
```

This code wouldn't throw the ConcurrentModificationException.

```
 List<String> al = new Arraylist<String>();
 Iterator<String> itr = al.iterator();
 while(itr.hasNext()){
   itr.next();
   itr.remove();
 }
```

You could also use some of the class's from [**java.util.Concurrent**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package such as [**java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) which wouldn't throw `ConcurrentModificationException` when you modify the list while iterating:

```
  CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> al = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
  al.add("2");
  Iterator<String> itr = al.iterator();
  while(itr.hasNext()){
  itr.next();
  al.add("3");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are removing elements in an ArrayList, use the Iterator. eg:

```
ArrayList<String> someStrings;
// fill someStrings
Iterator<String> it = someStrings.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
   String buf = it.next();
   // do sth here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when you add/remove/insert elements in the ArrayList while you are iterating over it.

Example of bad code:

```
Iterator it = list.iterator()
while (it.hasNext())
{
    Object o = it.next();
    list.remove(o);
}
```